# sorted container that is not a priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

we need a container that keeps its elements sorted by the element's priority when appending a new element, that has the ability to retrieve  an element given it's id.

(the problem with priority queue is that it doesn't give you the ability to retrieve an element according to id and not priority)

thanks

Comment: *All* containers give you the ability to retrieve an element according to any criteria. Did you forget something?

Comment: How about creating your own container that wraps two other containers that efficiently allow the operations that you want.

Comment: @Jon  - I lets say i want the third element in the priority queue. how do i get it? couldn't find the right function here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @Jon - priority queues are container adapters, not containers. Specifically, they don't have `.begin()` or `.end()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[boost multi index containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) give you the ability to have a sorted view on priority and a sorted view on ID.

A small example:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>

struct elem {
  std::size_t id;
  int priority;
};

int main()
{
  using namespace boost::multi_index;

  typedef multi_index_container<
  elem,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member<elem,std::size_t,&elem::id> >,
    ordered_non_unique<member<elem,int,&elem::priority> >
    >
  > elem_container;


  // just for show
  std::vector<elem> elems = 
    {{0, 25}, 
     {1, 10}, 
     {2, 100}, 
     {3, 6}
    };
  elem_container elemc(begin(elems), end(elems));
  // by id
  std::cout << "By ID: " << std::endl;
  for(auto& x : elemc.get<0>()) { 
    std::cout << "id: " << x.id << "priority: " << x.priority << std::endl;
  }

  // by priority
  std::cout << "By Priority: " << std::endl;
  for(auto& x : elemc.get<1>()) { 
    std::cout << "id: " << x.id << "priority: " << x.priority << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: we are not allowed to use boost :(

Comment: @kakush And this just when I was finished typing up an example to show you how easy it is.

Comment: @kakush: yes, life can be tough.  You can do this yourself, but it requires some bookkeeping during insert/remove/sort/... which is not easy to get right.

Comment: @pmr: nice example, nice C++11

Comment: @stefaanv I think if someone takes a stab at a C++11 multi-index the typedef could be much more intuitive, but that is left as an exercise to the reader ;)